# Hostapd start error

Tags: unix, debian

make wthis this manual 
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd

with this config file

```
interface=wlan2
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=SupaAP
country_code=RU
hw_mode=g
channel=5
preamble=1
macaddr_acl=0

auth_algs=1
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=3
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[SHORT-GI-20][RX-STBC1]
wmm_enabled=1
```

and i have error

```
oot@Cubian:/home/cubie/wif/hostapd-2.1/hostapd# ./hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 16: unknown configuration item 'ieee80211n'
Line 17: unknown configuration item 'ht_capab'
2 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to initialize interfac
```

in old version i dont have thsi error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

in compile conf i uncomment string

```
CONFIG_IEEE80211N=y
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the problem is that hostapd 2.1 is now treating an error it had differently.
This is reproducible on Ubuntu desktop versions, as the resource (WLAN) is busy.

If one turns off the programs that are accessing the resource, hostapd has a chance to grab it and work.

In Ubuntu desktop 14.04 beta, a solution is to turn off the programs that are using the wlan in question.

This worked for me:

```
sudo nmcli nm wifi off
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

then hostapd can start normally from command line.  Of course, if you want hostapd to start on boot you must insure that the network manager is not grabbing the resource ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link explaining the cause of the error and how to solve it.
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/20269

Also I have found this other link http://blog.mirjamali.com/en/IT/Linux/hostapd which I followed and it is working with me check the configuration part.

My OS is ubuntu 12.4

Answer (score 0):

start your hostapd with

```
hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

you will get more information for diagnostics. In which old version you did not get the error? Did you update hostapd? Or changed your wifi adapter? which distri you are using?

http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf

there is written how the ieee80211n settings are. for me i cant see an error.
if you remove the both lines, the ap is starting correctly?